# Wordpress: get_categories for custom post type, with custom taxonomies, filtered by category

Tags: database, wordpress

I have a pretty advanced problem that hopefully somebody on here can help me with. I have the following:

custom post type of 'Products'

custom taxonomy of 'brands'

& the standard taxonomy of 'category'

Each 'Product' is tagged with a 'brand' and placed in a parent and child category

I need to do the following:

archive.php page displays all the 'categories' which have 'Products' in them that have the 'brand' taxonomy with a value of the 'brand' whos page it is. **This works fine with the function below thanks to @MikeSchinkel**

```
$term = get_query_var('term');
    $brand = get_term_by('slug',$term,'brands'); // This here just to illustrate
    $categories = get_cross_referenced_terms(array(
    'post_type'        => 'Products',
    'taxonomy'         => 'category',
    'related_taxonomy' => 'brands',
    'term_id'          => $brand->term_id
  ));
```

Which uses the following function:

```
// query to get categories for a specific tag
function get_cross_referenced_terms($args) {
  global $wpdb;
  $args = wp_parse_args($args,array(
    'post_type'        => 'Products',
    'taxonomy'         => 'category',
    'related_taxonomy' => 'brands',
    'term_id'          => 0,
  ));
  extract($args);
  $sql = <<<SQL
SELECT DISTINCT
  {$wpdb->terms}.*,
  COUNT(*) AS post_count
FROM
  {$wpdb->terms}
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} ON {$wpdb->terms}.term_id={$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_id
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_taxonomy_id={$wpdb->term_relationships}.term_taxonomy_id
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->posts} ON {$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id={$wpdb->posts}.ID
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} related_relationship ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID=related_relationship.object_id
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} related_term_taxonomy ON related_relationship.term_taxonomy_id=related_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} related_terms ON related_term_taxonomy.term_id=related_terms.term_id
WHERE 1=1
  AND related_terms.term_id<>{$wpdb->terms}.term_id
  AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_type='%s'
  AND {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.taxonomy='%s'
  AND related_term_taxonomy.taxonomy='%s'
  AND related_terms.term_id=%d
  AND {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.parent=0
GROUP BY
  {$wpdb->terms}.term_id
SQL;
  $sql = $wpdb->prepare($sql,$post_type,$taxonomy,$related_taxonomy,$term_id);
  $terms = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
  return $terms;
}
```

This displays all the categories for the specified brand and works spot on. But now I need it to be able to set the 'child_of' for the category pages. So all I need to add (I think) is the ability to query the category id or specify a category parent. Something like:

```
'child_of' => $parent_category
```

I think it may be something I could add in the database query here:

```
AND {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.parent=0
```

But its a bit out of my league! If anybody could help me out I'd be very grateful!

Thankyou

Dave

Answer (score 0):

yes you are close. this might work:

```
AND {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.parent=[$term_id}
```

if you want only the children of the brand you are passing, otherwise if you need to pass that in separately, you could add to the args in the function provided

for example:

```
    'term_id'          => 0,
    'parent_id'          => 0,
));
```

and then below you would use that new variable

```
AND {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.parent=[$parent_id}
```